# Laravel: What is the best practice in testing controller

Tags: php, unit-testing, view, controller, laravel-4

I'm using laravel 4 and trying to write a test for controller with a mock up of the business logic which pass some fake data.
Then I encounter errors in rendering view due to missing of variables.

First of all, I didn't expect that the view will be rendered, so I didn't care to pass the exact data structure that is needed.
Should I pass the correct data structure to the view or is there a way to stop view from rendering in the test? Which is the better practice and why?

Moreover, after attempting to imitate data structure passing by business logic, there is still error cause by permission of user.
The result temp file of the view has been generated by web user (www-data) and I don't have permission to modify it.
I know, I can just chmod 777, but this is clearly not a good practice, if I have to do that for every time I want to run the test.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't tried testing yet but what i would assume you can do is try an echo statement or dd() function without the View::make(). Then go into terminal and type curl http://yourdomain.com/my/path.. to get results. There is also "php artisan tinker" i think it gives information of whats going on. take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your controllers are not messed up. Every logic should be injected through constructor or resolved from the IOC. Mock external classes and bind mocked instances on your test setUp. Facades already have support for Mockery. You can use XXX::shouldReceive().

Also, I suggest you to take a look at Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase. It has helper methods like assertViewHas, assertSessionHas, assertRedirectedTo etc. With these, testing your controller will be really easy.

After all, best thing to do for you would be reading "Laravel Testing Decoded" by Jeffrey Way.  It'a short and amazing book. https://leanpub.com/laravel-testing-decoded

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't have problem with mock up. Maybe I'm not being clear. I want to somehow, in the test environment, stop the view from being rendered and whether if that is a good practice?

Comment: Also, before I can assert, without modify the permission on the view file (result of the view not blade), there was an error due to permission issue as those files got generated by www-data user.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem with the view breaking up while testing. in my case it was a foreach loop, that didn't get the right structure, so i changed my mock to return an empty array, this made the test pass. so this is a possible solution for you i think, though it doesn't mock or just forget rendering the view itself.